# How to use Google Adwords (and Google Tag Manager/Analytics) with nuxt.js App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I have a nuxt App which makes use of the nuxt community module `gtm-module`:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module/ which takes care of google tag manager stuff.

I now have the case that I need to add Adwords into the mix.
According to this source (https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en#adapt_gtag) it should be easy to just add another config id – the `AW-CONVERSION_ID` – to my global site tag.

Unfortunately the `gtm-module` does neither describe how to handle Adwords nor how to add custom stuff to the site tag.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID">   </script>

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
  gtag('config','AW-CONVERSION_ID'); // THIS IS WHAT I NEED ADDITIONALLY
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish the described solution here (https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en#adapt_gtag) but with the nuxt gtm community module?

Help is very much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It seems there is no need to use this AW Conversion ID. When setting up google tag manager, it should be alright. At least that is my experience so far...

Answer (score 0):

Try **@nuxtjs/google-tag** module, since it looks it has more options. https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-gtag

Comment: I do know that one, but they say that one should consider using the gtm-module... So I thought it is just an older version of that...